# How to identify a keylogger

Tags: keylogger

I know that a keylogger had been installed in my girlfriend computer, what is the best way to find it? how do I get the email address that the keylogger is addressing the information?

Comment: "what is the best way to find it?" a malware scanner?

Comment: @vcsjones Oh, I suppose he doesn't know... maybe that's why he asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably remove the keylogger, but unless it's really amateur software, I wouldn't bet on finding out the email address the alerts are going to, as it most likely sends that information securely, and the program is most likely hidden.

As a precaution, backup any important data and run the following programs:

1. [Rkill](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/rkill/) - it will close any active malicious software (and hopefully your keylogger). The log may also give you a hint as to what specific program you are fighting.
2. [TDSS Killer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/tdsskiller/) - checks for any rootkits that would hide the keylogger from showing up in windows.
3. [Combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) - Constantly updated removal program that is trained to remove an array of malware. This software is really powerful but can also get messed up if you're badly infected. Like I said, backup your data first.
4. [Kaspersky Anti-virus](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-home-trials/anti-virus) - Download the trial and run a deep scan. I seem to remember it being pretty decent at finding keyloggers.
5. [Malwarebytes](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/malwarebytes-anti-malware/) - Run full scan. Can catch stuff that a lot of commercial antiviruses miss.
6. [HitmanPro](http://www.surfright.nl/en) - Download the free version and scan. Catches stuff everyone else misses.

It's a lot of scans but hopefully the first three scanners remove it all and the rest is just extra assurance.  If you still think you're infected, run [HiJackThis](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hjt/) and post the logfile here. It will list all startup items and services.

-Good luck and happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

open task manager and try to identify unknown running process.

Answer (score 0):

Best chance you have is to download some software build to find keyloggers. Most keyloggers run in stealth mode, and thus dont show up much of anywhere.